# How do I make a Rake Task run after all other tasks? (i.e. a Rake AfterBuild task)

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm new to Rake and using it to build .net projects.  What I'm interested in is having a Summary task that prints out a summary of what has been done.  I want this task to always be called, no matter what tasks rake was invoked with.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Thanks

---

Update on the question, responding to [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689504/how-do-i-make-a-rake-task-run-after-all-other-tasks-i-e-a-rake-afterbuild-tas/1722979#1722979) what I want is the after task to run once after all other tasks, so the output I want is:

```
task :test1 do 
  puts 'test1'
end

task :test2 do 
  puts 'test2'
end

Rake::Task.tasks.each do |t|
    <Insert rake magic here>
#  t.enhance do 
#    puts 'after'
#  end
end

$ rake test1
test1
after

$rake test2
test2
after

$rake test1 test2  
test1
test2
after
```

and if

```
task :test3 =>[:test1, :test2]
   puts 'test3'
end

    $rake test3
test1
test2
test3
after
```

Even though the bounty is gone, any further help much appreciated.  (Sadily I don't think that I can offer another bounty.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posting this as a new answer to keep the other one available. This is much less elegant as I have to get into the guts of Rake and manually update the task list, but it works.

```
task :test1 do
  puts 'test1'
end

task :test2 do 
  puts 'test2'
end

task :after do
  puts 'after'
end

# top_level_tasks is't writable so we need to do this ugly
# instance_variable_set hack...
current_tasks =  Rake.application.top_level_tasks
current_tasks << :after
Rake.application.instance_variable_set(:@top_level_tasks, current_tasks)
```

Outputs:

```
$ rake test1
test1
after

$ rake test1 test2
test1
test2
after
```

Comment: GREAT!  

This is exactly what I want.  I would love to know what magic is going on here.  Can you give me more of an explination of what's happening?  In the mean time, I'll see what I can find on google.

Comment: Sure. As an aside, I'm at a conference and tracked down Jim Weirich (the author of rake) to see if this wis the best way to solve the problem. His answer was that Rake doesn't have a built in way to do this, but he's open to a patch if someone can come up with a generalized method for doing it.

So the code: The Rake application has a reader to keep track of the tasks to run called 'top_level_tasks'. Because it's read only we need to read it out, update it and then use instance_variable_set to push the change back into the application. If it was read write we could to it all in one line.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRitchie that's great! Btw it will work on one line, like this: `Rake.application.instance_variable_set(:@top_level_tasks, Rake.application.top_level_tasks + [:'printbot:status'])`.

Comment: You don't need to use instance_variable_set at all— ```Rake.application.top_level_tasks << :after``` will work just fine.

Answer (score 41):

You should be able to do this with 'enhance':

```
Rake::Task["my_task"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["my_after_task"].invoke
end
```

This will cause 'my_after_task' to be invoked after 'my_task'.

If you want to apply this to all tasks, just loop over all the tasks and call enhance for each:

```
Rake::Task.tasks.each do |t| 
  t.enhance do 
    Rake::Task["my_after_task"].invoke
  end
end
```

Full test file:

```
task :test1 do 
  puts 'test1'
end

task :test2 do 
  puts 'test2'
end

Rake::Task.tasks.each do |t|
  t.enhance do 
    puts 'after'
  end
end
```

And the output:

```
$ rake test1
test1
after

$ rake test2
test2
after
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I didn't state my question clearly.  I want the after task to run once, after other tasks are complete.

So: $ rake test1 test2 
would output
test1
test2
after

$rake test1
test1
after

$rake test2
test2
after

Any idea how to make that happen?

Comment: Ah ok, found a solution for you. Less elegant but it works. If you're interested I can explain in detail what I'm doing to get this to work...

Answer (score 12):

Found this simple elegant answer [here](https://coderwall.com/p/smghmw) that uses the Ruby method [`at_exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit).

It's worth noting that the method defined after `at_exit` will run every time the rake script is invoked regardless of the task run, or if any task is run. This includes when running `rake -T` (to list available tasks). Make sure that `at_exit` only does anything if a previous task told it to do so.

`rakefile.rb`

```
desc "Lovely task a"
task :a do
  puts "a"
end

desc "Lovely task b"
task :b do
  puts "b"
end

task :cleanup do
  puts "cleanup"
end

at_exit { Rake::Task[:cleanup].invoke if $!.nil? }
```

shell

```
$ rake a b
a
b
cleanup
$ rake -T
rake a # Lovely task a
rake b # Lovely task b
cleanup
```

You also don't need to make it run a task if you don't want to.

```
at_exit do
  puts "cleanup"
end
```

Or make it run an method

```
def on_exit_do_cleanup
  puts "cleanup"
end

at_exit { on_exit_do_cleanup }
```

And you may want to make sure you only do the cleanup if a task actually ran so that `rake -T` won't also do a cleanup.

`rakefile.rb`

```
do_cleanup = false

desc "Lovely task a"
task :a do
  puts "a"
  do_cleanup = true
end

desc "Lovely task b"
task :b do
  puts "b"
  do_cleanup = true
end

task :cleanup do
  return unless $!.nil? # No cleanup on error
  return unless do_cleanup # No cleanup if flag is false
  puts "cleanup"
end

at_exit { Rake::Task[:cleanup].invoke }
```

Comment: what is $!.nil? denotes..?

Comment: `$!` contains the last raised error and `x.nil?` returns true if the `x` is `nil` so, `... if $!.nil?` is making sure the cleanup task only runs if there were no errors in this run of the script. (Edited answer for clarification)

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the ugly `Rake.application.instance_variable_set`, you can enhance the last task on the command-line like so:

```
  last_task = Rake.application.top_level_tasks.last
  Rake::Task[last_task].enhance do
    puts 'after'
  end
```

That should do exactly what you need to do!

Comment: You have one `end` at the end that shouldn't be there, I guess.

Comment: Interesting.  The accepted solution below is working, and I haven't had to modify the script for ages, but next time I do I'll look at using this method.  It is definitely more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Kernel.trap call and attach to the "Exit" signal. It will fire upon both normal and abnormal exit.

Put this early in your rakefile:

```
Kernel.trap("EXIT") do
  Rake::Task[:final].invoke
end
```

Now any time you make a "final" task it will be executed at the very end of the program. no matter what.

```
task :final do
  puts "Hit return to continue..."
  STDIN.getc
end
```

Comment: Cool.  Thanks.  I'll try this next time I need it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way but it's the simpler:

Make all your "public tasks" Summary ones that call real tasks.

```
task :compile => :realcompile do
   summary stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came here looking for how to run a task *before* all other tasks (eg, a special env loading task), you can still use the same enhance method, except only the first arguement:

```
task :environment do
  env = (ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'production').downcase
  # do things before other tasks
end

# run environment task before all tasks for setup
Rake::Task.tasks.each do |t|
  next if t.name == 'environment'
  t.enhance [:environment]
end
```