# Run one rake task after another completes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to split down a rake task that i have,

What im wanting to do is after the rake task completes, It fires off another rake task.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`enhance`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Rake/Task/enhance) to extend one task with other:

```
task :extra_behavior do
  # extra
end

Rake::Task["first:task"].enhance do
  Rake::Task[:extra_behavior].invoke
end
```

- [`Reference`](http://edgar.tumblr.com/post/52300664342/how-to-extend-an-existing-rake-task)
- [`Reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1722979/2057388)

Answer (score 4):

Passing a task as an argument to enhance causes it to run BEFORE the task you are "enhancing".

```
Rake::Task["task_A"].enhance(["task_B"])
# Runs task_B
# Runs task_A
```

Passing a task to enhance in a block causes it to run AFTER the task you are "enhancing".

```
Rake::Task["task_A"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["task_B"].execute
end
# Runs task_A
# Runs task_B
```

Reference: [Rake Task enhance Method Explained](https://dev.to/molly_struve/rake-task-enhance-method-explained-3bo0)